# Customizing UIVIewController/UIWebview with just image and text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, rss-reader

I am almost done completing an RSS Feed app for an internship and everything is going well but now my boss wants the article page format to be: Article title on top, article picture below that followed by the article text underneath instead of just the mobile web view that comes up.

Here is the mobile view that I already have after clicking on the article cell:

[image]

And here is what I want it to look like:

[image]

The code for my webview is in my RSSDetail.m file that I got from open source code. This is my first app making experience ever so I am not quite sure how to work around this. Here is the code:

```
#import "RSSDetail.h"

@interface RSSDetail ()

@end

@implementation RSSDetail

@synthesize feedURL, webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //load Web View URL
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:feedURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark - WebView delegate

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webV {

self.title = [webV stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    }

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    //log errors loading, normal on WebViews
    NSLog(@"Error Loading: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

@end
```

I can also post any other relevant code that might be useful and I also have the full project up on my github in case anyone wants to see all the code or download it and try it on xcode yourself.

I would really like to do well here so any help is extremely useful to me. Thanks

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: I would like to load the article like the second picture I posted (I created that in paint to serve as the example). So when an article is clicked on it will load the page with the title, picture underneath and then the article text under the photo instead of loading the whole mobile site view

Comment: that is not a question. What is not working right now?

Comment: It is working but I would like the web view to be cleaned up to look like the second picture. Instead of the full mobile view shown in the first picI would like it to just contain the title, pic and article text

Comment: Well just add a UILabel, UIImageView, and UITextView.

Comment: I figured that was the way to go but the reason I posted the question is because I am new to this and I am using an open source code, so I figured maybe someone could either direct me towards a great tutorial on it or provide a little tutorial themselves since I'm not quite sure how to code the labels and views to get the data from the site

Comment: That's kind of a question =D Have you read this yet? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html